# How to verify a user's token in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When using the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method, I get a `refreshToken` and save it to state redux.

I would like to check this token for validity with firebase. How can I do this?

Maybe I should save `getIdToken`?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you trying to verify and/or save the token, as Firebase already does both?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I need this to check the validity of the user's token so that it is not replaced

Comment: That's still a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It really helps if you ask yourself a path of "why" questions here. Why does replacing the token matter (note: I have no idea what you mean here, but will assume that it makes sense to you)? Why do you need to check the validity of the token, given that Firebase already handles that for you? What are you trying to do with the token that makes you need to validate it? Why can't you leave it to Firebase, which already does that for you?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Because I have a task: Implement the componentDidMount method in the component of the initial page with the verification of the user's token on the backend (if the token is invalid, then it is necessary to return the user to the authorization page).

Comment: Verifying the ID token on a custom backend is well documented: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens. I'm still not certain you need that here though: the Firebase Auth SDK already checks when the token expires (or needs refreshing for other reasons) and if you [use an auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) or [use an ID token listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#onidtokenchanged) to detect changes in auth state or ID tokens respectively.